# Get full row with a join based on max value

Tags: mysql, subquery, max

In mysql I have these two tables:

```
**Seasons**
id
number
current

**Episodes**
id
number
season_id
other_info
```

I want to get a full row from `Episodes`, the joined row from `Seasons` all based on the max `number` value of both table.

For example, if I have Seasons 1, 2, 3, I want to get the latest episode from the most recent Season.

I started with this query:

```
SELECT e.id as episode_id, s.id as season_id, MAX(s.number) AS season_number, MAX(e.number) AS episode_number, e.other_info
FROM (episodes AS e)
JOIN seasons AS s ON e.season_id=s.id
WHERE s.current =  1
```

It kind of works, but then it shows the wrong `other_info` value. I understood that it's because `MAX()` groups rows, but the other values are kind of random, so I think it's just displaying `other_info` from the first row available.

Looking around I've found this which I thought would've worked, but it didn't:

```
SELECT e.id as episode_id, s.id as season_id, MAX(s.number) AS season_number, MAX(e.number) AS episode_number, e.other_info
FROM (episodes AS e)
JOIN seasons AS s ON e.season_id=s.id
WHERE s.current =  1 AND
e.number = (select max(sube.number) from episodes sube);
```

In this case I just get all NULL values.

Comment: Do you really want the `MAX(number)` from `seasons`, or do you want `current = 1`? Your queries suggest that `current` is a boolean indicating the row is the "latest" season.

Comment: And is this query expected to return one row from one show (or whatever this is) or would it ever need to involve the latest episode grouped by each of many different shows? The approaches can differ dramatically.

Comment: The final query should be correct except, you do not need the MAX of s.number or e.number (your where clause takes care of that).

Comment: You're correct about `current`, it's a boolean. It's set to 1 in the latest season and I added it to simplify the query, but I would like to use the MAX() function. And I need just one row, which should contain just the latest episode from the latest season

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you:

```
SELECT seasons.*, episodes.* 
FROM episodes
INNER JOIN seasons ON episodes.season_id = seasons.id
ORDER BY seasons.number DESC ,episodes.number DESC 
limit 0,1
```

Comment: ok, this is way simpler and probably more efficient than my approach. Thank you.